# Unable to create a plane of Points

Tags: java

I am trying to create a plane of Points with this code:

Class environment:

```
public class Environment {
public ArrayList<Point> plane = new ArrayList<Point>();


public void addToPlane(Point point) {
    plane.add(point);
}
public void showplane() {
    for(int x=1; x<=2500; x++) {
        Point point2 = new Point();
        point2 = plane.get(x);
        System.out.println("x = "+point2.getX()+"; y = "+point2.getY());
    }
}
```

}

Class EnvironmentTest:

```
    public class EnvironmentTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Environment env = new Environment();
        Helper help = new Helper();

        help.createPlane(env,50,50);
        env.showplane();
    }

}
```

Class helper:

```
    public class Helper {

    public void createPlane(Environment env, int i, int j) {
        Point point = new Point();
        for(int x=0; x<=i; x++) {
            for(int y=0; y<=j; y++) {   
                point.setLocation(x, y);
                System.out.println(x+"+"+y);
                env.addToPlane(point);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I get in console when i run showplane() is

```
...
50+38
50+39
50+40
50+41
...
```

Everything is fine by now but when i try to list my points I get only:

```
x = 50.0; y = 50.0
x = 50.0; y = 50.0
x = 50.0; y = 50.0
x = 50.0; y = 50.0
x = 50.0; y = 50.0
```

Where do I make mistake?

Comment: You're using a single `Point`, so the entire contents of `plane` will reference the single `Point`, which will have the last coordinates.

Answer (score 3):

```
//Point point = new Point(); // removed
for(int x=0; x<=i; x++) {
    for(int y=0; y<=j; y++) {   
        Point point = new Point(); // added
        point.setLocation(x, y);
        System.out.println(x+"+"+y);
        env.addToPlane(point);
    }
}
```

You only create one Point object (so the same values get displayed over and over). You need to create a new Point object in the loop for every point.

Comment: That's weird. I change location of the point every iteration of the for loop and then add it to the list as new point with new coords. Java can't change coords of the old point? @camickr

Comment: I get it now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You're using the same Point object over and over, create a new one right before setLocation()